# Performing a weighted repeated measures ANOVA in R or SPSS

Tags: r, spss, anova, weighted

I would like to conduct a weighted repeated measures ANOVA with 3 (related) groups.

Some hypothetical data:

```
Data = data.frame(
       ID = as.factor(1:10),
       DV = c(0.06, 0.23, -0.2, 0.8, 0.67, 0.11, 0.88, -0.04, -0.4, 0.5, 0.07,-0.1, 0.3, 0.02, 0.03, 0.6, 0.65, 0.2, 0.15, -0.15,-0.02, 0.04, 0, 0.5, -0.4, 0.6, 0.3, 0.12, 0.33, -0.02), 
       Weight = c(13, 5, 60, 45, 2, 90, 110, 54, 27, 25,84, 40, 23, 60, 10, 7, 100, 89, 73, 44,30, 68, 92, 34, 12, 30, 87, 35, 28, 88),
       IV = rep(c("Short","Medium","Long"), each=10)
)
```

I want to weigh the DV by the numbers in the Data$Weight column. For example, the DV=0.06 should contribute 13 times, the DV=0.23 only 5 times.

I have tried to do this using either:

```
library(ez)
library(nlme)
modelaov = aov(DV ~ IV + Error(ID/IV), weights=W, data=Data)
modellme = lme(DV ~ IV, random = ~1|ID/IV, weights=Data$W, data=Data)
```

I get error messages with both attempts, and I don't know how to solve them.

I also tried do to this in SPSS, using a weighted least squares regression, but there I have the issue of not being able to select dependent cases.

Hopefully anyone can be of help!

Answer (score 2):

The help for `nlme::lme()` states for the `weights` argument:

> an optional varFunc object or one-sided formula describing the within-group heteroscedasticity structure. If given as a formula, it is used as the argument to varFixed, corresponding to fixed variance weights. See the documentation on varClasses for a description of the available varFunc classes. Defaults to NULL, corresponding to homoscedastic within-group errors.

Maybe the argument does not work that way.

Perhaps you could just replicate each row by the desired weight and then run the model like so:

```r
library(purrr)
library(nlme)

Data = data.frame(
       ID = as.factor(1:10),
       DV = c(0.06, 0.23, -0.2, 0.8, 0.67, 0.11, 0.88, -0.04, -0.4, 0.5, 0.07,-0.1, 0.3, 0.02, 0.03, 0.6, 0.65, 0.2, 0.15, -0.15,-0.02, 0.04, 0, 0.5, -0.4, 0.6, 0.3, 0.12, 0.33, -0.02), 
       Weight = c(13, 5, 60, 45, 2, 90, 110, 54, 27, 25,84, 40, 23, 60, 10, 7, 100, 89, 73, 44,30, 68, 92, 34, 12, 30, 87, 35, 28, 88),
       IV = rep(c("Short","Medium","Long"), each=10)
) %>% 
  map_df(rep, .$Weight)

modellme = lme(DV ~ IV, random = ~1|ID/IV, data=Data)
summary(modellme)
#> Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
#>   Data: Data 
#>        AIC       BIC  logLik
#>   -98353.6 -98321.87 49182.8
#> 
#> Random effects:
#>  Formula: ~1 | ID
#>          (Intercept)
#> StdDev: 9.513974e-15
#> 
#>  Formula: ~1 | IV %in% ID
#>         (Intercept)     Residual
#> StdDev:   0.5281456 2.971485e-16
#> 
#> Fixed effects:  DV ~ IV 
#>                  Value  Std.Error   DF    t-value p-value
#> (Intercept)  0.0082162 0.01124611 1435   0.730580  0.4652
#> IVMedium    -0.4753554 0.01688691   18 -28.149337  0.0000
#> IVShort     -0.0453449 0.01826811   18  -2.482187  0.0231
#>  Correlation: 
#>          (Intr) IVMedm
#> IVMedium -0.666       
#> IVShort  -0.616  0.410
#> 
#> Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
#>        Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
#> -1.8681284 -0.1868128  0.0000000  0.4670321  2.3351605 
#> 
#> Number of Observations: 1465
#> Number of Groups: 
#>         ID IV %in% ID 
#>         10         30
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank your pointing this out, I have incorporated these changes.  
I do get a different answer when comparing the results from the aov versus lme model:
with modelaov = aov(DV ~ IV + Error(ID/IV), weight=Weight, data=Data)
summary(modelaov), the p-value > 0.05, but when I compare the lme model (lme(DV ~ IV, random = ~1|ID/IV, data=Data2, method="ML")) to a baseline model (lme(DV ~ 1, random = ~1|ID/IV, data=Data2, method="ML")), there is a significant effect. Do you know how to explain this difference?

Comment: As CIAndrews pointed out, the above method increases the number of observations which is the most likely contributer to the change in significance. However, also note that the fitting algorithms differ with weighted least squares vs maximum likelihood.

Answer (score 1):

As your dataset using `Weight` to set the weights, using that variable name is step 1. Next, in `aov` you should use `weight = variable name` instead of `weights`:

`modelaov = aov(DV ~ IV + Error(ID/IV), weight=Weight, data=Data)`

For `lme` this works for me:
`lme(DV~IV,random=~1|ID/IV,weights=~Weight, data = Data)`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the stupid mistakes I made. I do get a different result (significant versus non-significant) by using the two different approaches (also when incorporating the suggestion by the-mad-statter, see comment above). Do you have any idea on how to explain this?

Comment: I'm not sure on that. But keep in mind that the approach by `the-mad-statter` increases the number of observations from 30 to 1,435. When you want to compare `aov` with `lme`, make sure you use the same dataset in both methods.

Comment: ooh, that's a good point - one may not wish to increase the number of observations